# Need help on locating which part of CNN needs to get either .cuda() or .to_device()

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Good day!

I've been struggling with the following error: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument target in method wrapper_nll_loss_forward)

I've been unable to locate where I need to add a part of my model to the GPU. From the error message I gather it should be in the loss function but I've tried all places I could think off, related to the loss function and have been unable to solve it.

Would love some help with this.

My full code can be found here:

https://huggingface.co/AFAD85/CNN_apples/blob/main/CNN%20paper%20clone%20pytorch.ipynb

I tried to isolate all possibly relevant code below:

```
`transformer = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((350,350)),
    transforms.ToTensor(), 
    transforms.Normalize([0.5,0.5,0.5],
                         [0.5,0.5,0.5])
])`



`class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,num_classes=4):
        super(ConvNet,self).__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=128,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding='valid')
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=128)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding='valid')
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding='valid')
        self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64)
        self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding='valid')
        self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=32)
        self.relu4 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool4 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding='valid')
        self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=32)
        self.relu5 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool5 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        self.flat = nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=2592, out_features = 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features = num_classes)

        
    def forward(self,input):
        output = self.conv1(input)
        output = self.bn1(output)
        output = self.relu1(output)
        output = self.pool1(output)
        
        output = self.conv2(output)
        output = self.bn2(output)
        output = self.relu2(output)
        output = self.pool2(output)
        
        output = self.conv3(output)
        output = self.bn3(output)
        output = self.relu3(output)
        output = self.pool3(output)
        
        output = self.conv4(output)
        output = self.bn4(output)
        output = self.relu4(output)
        output = self.pool4(output)
        
        output = self.conv5(output)
        output = self.bn5(output)
        output = self.relu5(output)
        output = self.pool5(output)
        
        # output = output.view(-1,32,9,9)
        
        output = self.flat(output)
        output = self.fc1(output)
        output = self.fc2(output)
        
        return output`
        


    model = ConvNet(num_classes=4).to(device)

    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001,weight_decay=0.0001)
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()



`best_accuracy = 0.0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    
    model.train()
    train_accuracy = 0.0
    train_loss = 0.0
    
    for i, (images,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        if torch.cuda.is_available():

            images = Variable(images.cuda())
            lables = Variable(labels.cuda())
    
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = loss_function(outputs,labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        train_loss += loss.cpu().data*images.size(0)
        _.prediction = torch.max(outputs.data,1)
        
        train_accuracy += int(torch.sum(prediction==labels.data))
    
    train_accuracy = train_accuracy/train_count
    train_loss = train_loss/train_count
    
    #test set evalueren
    model.eval()
    
    test_accuracy = 0.0
    for i, (images,labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            images = Variable(images.cuda())
            lables = Variable(labels.cuda())
        
        outputs = model(images)
        _.prediction = torch.max(outputs.data,1)
        
    test_accuracy = test_accuracy/test_count

    print('Epoch: '+str(epoch)+' Train Loss: '+str(int(train_loss)))+' Train Accuracy: '+str(train_accuracy)+' Test Accuracy: '+str(test_accuracy)


    if test_accuracy > best_accuracy:
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'best_checkpoint.model')`
```

I tried to have the model run an epoch, expecting it to run on the GPU.

I tried adding .cuda() and .to_device() in all places where I expected the problem might lie, but was unable to find the correct one.

Comment: Looked through it one more time after posting and found this line :    

train_loss += loss.cpu().data*images.size(0)
changing the .cpu to .cuda or .to_device() didn't solve it unfortunatly

Comment: what is you intention from this line `_.prediction` , you should change to `_, prediction`

Comment: Unfortunate typo I'm afraid ^^ thanks for pointing it out, changed it.

Comment: does that fixed you problem ? I do not see the error you are seeing, print the error if you still have

Comment: Didn't fix it, tried the above mentioned .cpu line and .cuda and .to_device error is as such:

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument target in method wrapper_nll_loss_forward)

Comment: do a model.get_parameters() and iterate over all the parameters (trainable) and look at their device , see which one is not on gpu.

Comment: and also I do not know it is again the problem in printing the code but model , optimizer and loss are all in wrong indentation, which means not in right scop

Comment: model.get_parameters() is returning the following error: AttributeError: 'ConvNet' object has no attribute 'get_parameters' tried googling how to fix this, but not getting there. Can print the model but that doesnt have any device indication. The model, optimizer and loss indentation is a result of my fumbling with the stackoverflow format, I apologize.

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: x.device, model.parameters()))`

Comment: Every line is : device(type='cuda', index=0), also thanks for spelling it out for me... Still very fresh with coding.

Comment: check device for output and labels and see if that is true even before starting the calculating loss and after

Comment: Put it between every cell (list(map(lambda x: x.device, model.parameters()))) and the same line on every occasion. Rebooted PC aswell (grasping at straws at this point) didnt help ofcourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a typo

```
            lables = Variable(labels.cuda())
```

where `lables` should be `labels`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! I can't believe it, read over it so many times...

Comment: You are welcome. Another note: torch.autograd.Variable has become deprecated in the stable version and is no longer necessary to use autograd feature. BTW, if you feel that the problem has been solved, you can accept my answer.

Comment: I've been using a fairly old tutorial (matched my use case very well). I'll see about getting rid of the autograd. Would that mean replacing images = Variable(images.cuda()) with just images = images.cuda()? I tried upvoting your answer, and am looking for a way to accept it (first time here sorry...) (found it)